# Python httplib2 WSSE example

Tags: python, httplib2, wsse

Does anyone have a working example of using httplib2 for WSSE authentication? I've looked around for one but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http.add_credentials("myusername", "mypassword")
```

Comment: This is for basic HTTP authentication, not WSSE.

Comment: It works for both Basic Auth and WSSE (provided as an HTTP header, not provided in the SOAP envelope).  I have an example of both server and client at http://runnable.com/VRCVAcJ7c7QaEvu5/itty-server-authenticates-via-wsse-for-python-and-authentication